# Rails simple_form number_field lost functionality?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I am new to simple_form and I was wondering if its possible to have a f.number_field functional like in normal rails. What I am interested in is the side 'increase'/'reduce' buttons and the posibility to inrease/reduce with mouse wheel or 'up/'down' keys..

Comment: ok I now understand that one way to do this is my using 'Wrapping Rails Form Helpers' way thats is shown on the documentation..Is this proper?

Answer (score 0):

I think a workaround is to pass `:as => :string` as an option

```
<%= f.input :number_field, :as => :string %>
```